# If $\lbrace y_{k}\rbrace_{k\in K}$ is a net such that $e^{ixy_{k}}\to 1$ pointwise, then $y_{k}\to 0$

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, abelian-groups, topological-groups

Okay, so my brain doesn't seem to be working right now. I'm trying to prove that, given a net $\lbrace y_{k}\rbrace_{k\in K}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $e^{ixy_{k}}$ converges pointwise to $1$ then $y_{k}$ necessarily goes to $0$. I know that if $y_{k}$ is bounded then there's a sufficiently large $n$ such that the whole net is contained in $[-n,n]$. Since this set is compact there must be a convergent subnet, say $y_{k_{j}}$. If we call its limit $y$ then $e^{ixy_{k_{i}}}\to e^{ixy}$ pointwise, so $e^{ixy_{k_{j}}}\to 1$ pointwise. Thus $e^{ixy}=1$ for all $x$. Then it must be the case that $y=0$. Otherwise we could take $x=\dfrac{\pi}{y}$ in $e^{ixy}=e^{i\pi}=-1$, which is a contradiction.

The only thing left to show is that $\lbrace y_{k}\rbrace_{k\in K}$ is bounded. If it wasn't we should be able to construct a subnet $\lbrace y_{k_{j}}\rbrace_{j\in J}$ (I'm pretty sure I can take it to be a sequence) that blows up to either $\infty$ or $-\infty$. In particular, we can assume without loss of generality that it blows up to $\infty$ (since the other case should be analogous). It seems intuitively true that this will lead to a contradiction, since plotting the real part of $e^{iax}$, $\cos(ax)$ for some $a\in\mathbb
{R}$ and letting $a\to\infty$ the resulting set of points appears to coincide (or at least be dense) in the band $(-\infty,\infty)\times[-1,1]$. This seems to imply that the set $(-\infty,\infty)\times\lbrace 1\rbrace$ is dense in this band, which is obviously false.

So, how should I go about proving that the original net $\lbrace y_{k}\rbrace_{k\in K}$ is bounded? Or am I approaching this in the wrong way? For context, I am trying to prove that $\mathbb{R}$ is homeomorphic to $\widehat{\mathbb{R}}$ (its dual group with the corresponding topology) via the identification $y\longmapsto e^{ixy}$. I already know this is a bijection (moreover, I know it defines a group isomorphism) and I know that mapping $y$ to $e^{ixy}$ is continuous. But I've been trying a lot of different approaches to show continuity in the other direction and nothing I've tried so far has worked. The idea I outlined in the post seems the most promising so far, since I know that convergence in the topology of $\widehat{\mathbb{R}}$ implies uniform convergence on compact sets (in particular, it implies pointwise convergence). All of that led me to the approach I described at the beginning.

For reference, I am following Chapter VII of John B. Conway's "A Course in Functional Analysis" (Second Edition). According to the author the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ and $\widehat{\mathbb{R}}$  are homeomorphic is easy to prove, but I've been thinking about this for two days straight and I've honestly ran out of ideas. Maybe I'm just too dumb to see it, I don't know. But I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Using uniform convergence on compact sets is much easier. Your typical neighbourhood of $0$ is then $\{y : \lvert e^{ixy} - 1\rvert < \varepsilon \text{ for all } x \in [-a,a]\}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Could you elaborate a little? I'm sorry but I'm burnt out and I can barely think at this point.

Comment: Does the answer help?

Comment: @DanielFischer Honestly, at this point I can't imagine what the set of $y$ such that $\vert e^{ixy}-1\vert<\epsilon$ for all $x\in[-a,a]$ looks like. To be completely frank I just want to get this over with. I've been working on this project for months and I'm just a few lines of text from the point I can consider it to be done. I don't want to spend any more time on this. I almost hate it by now. And there's also other things I have to start working on.

Comment: Take such a $y$. Then $x \mapsto e^{ixy}$, $x \in [0,a]$ is a curve that never is farther away from $1$ than $\varepsilon$, starting at $1$. And $xy$ starts at $0$. Since $\lvert e^{it} - 1\rvert = 2 \lvert \sin \frac{t}{2}\rvert$, that means $\lvert\sin \frac{xy}{2}\rvert < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ for $0 \leqslant x \leqslant a$. When $\varepsilon < 2$ this means $\frac{\lvert xy\rvert}{2} < \arcsin \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ for $x \in [0,a]$, hence $\lvert y\rvert < \frac{2}{a}\arcsin \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$. That's just an interval whose length is more or less proportional to $\varepsilon$.

Comment: @DanielFischer After thinking about it for a while, I got my head around the argument. It was a lot simpler than I thought, although I don't know if I could have come up with $\vert e^{it}−1\vert=2\vert\sin(\frac{t}{2})\vert$. Anyway, in the state I was a few hours ago I couldn't think straight. I apologize if I was harsh, I've been pretty stressed out lately. And thank you for your patience.

Comment: $\lvert e^{it} - 1\rvert = 2\lvert \sin \frac{t}{2}\rvert$ is an identity that one uses occasionally. It's not hard to derive (even if one doesn't know what the right hand side should be), provided one is not stressed or frustrated. [That's general, if stressed or frustrated one does not see things one otherwise would.] One way to get it is multiplying with $e^{-it/2}$, $\lvert e^{it}-1\rvert = \lvert e^{-it/2}\rvert\cdot \lvert e^{it}-1\rvert = \lvert e^{it/2} - e^{-it/2}\rvert$. If you spend a calm half hour on it, I'm sure you can find a couple of other ways to prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A net $(y_k)_{k \in K}$ such that $e^{ixy_k} \to 1$ pointwise need not converge to $0$.

Take an arbitrary finite set $\{ x_{\nu} : 1 \leqslant \nu \leqslant n\} \subset \mathbb{R}$ and consider the point
$$\xi = (e^{ix_1}, \dotsc, e^{ix_n}) \in T^n\,.$$
Since $T^n$ is compact, the sequence $(\xi^m)_{m \in \mathbb{N}}$ has a limit point $\eta$. Then for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there are infinitely many $m \in \mathbb{N}$ with $\lvert e^{ix_{\nu}m} - \eta_{\nu}\rvert < \varepsilon$ for all $\nu$. Taking two such $m$, we see that there are arbitrarily large integers $r = m_1 - m_2$ such that $\lvert e^{ix_{\nu}r} - 1\rvert < 2\varepsilon$ for $1 \leqslant \nu \leqslant n$.

Thus if we take for $K$ the directed set $\mathscr{F} \times (0,1) \times \mathbb{N}$, where $\mathscr{F}$ is the set of finite subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, and the preorder is given by
$$(F_1, \varepsilon_1, m_1) \leqslant (F_2, \varepsilon_2, m_2) \iff F_1 \subseteq F_2 \land \varepsilon_2 \leqslant \varepsilon_1 \land m_1 \leqslant m_2$$
we obtain a net $(y_k)_{k \in K}$ such that $y_k \to +\infty$ and $e^{ixy_k} \to 1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ by setting
$$y_{F, \varepsilon, m} = \min \{ \mu \in \mathbb{N} : \mu \geqslant m \land \lvert e^{ix\mu} - 1\rvert \leqslant \varepsilon \text{ for all } x \in F\}\,.$$

The topology of pointwise convergence is too coarse. You need to use the uniform convergence on compact sets, and the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is locally compact. Thus convergence in $\widehat{\mathbb{R}}$ implies (is) locally uniform convergence, and for $a > 0$ the set of $y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\lvert e^{ixy} - 1\rvert \leqslant \varepsilon$ holds for all $x \in [-a,a]$ is (for small enough $\varepsilon$) easy to determine.

Comment: I also looked at the counterexample you gave. I only have one question. It is not so obvious to me that with this choice of the $y_{k}$ the sequence $e^{ixy_{k}}$ converges pointwise. Correct me if I'm wrong: is it because I can consider $y_{\lbrace x\rbrace,\epsilon,1}=y_{k_{0}}$, for fixed $x$ and any $\epsilon$ and then since I know that the set of $\mu$ such that satisfy $\mu\geq m$ and $\vert e^{ix\mu}-1\vert\leq\epsilon$ is non-empty I know that $y_{k_{0}}$ is well-defined so that whenever I choose $k\in K$ such that $k\geq k_{0}$ I have that $\vert e^{ixy_{k}}-1\vert\leq\epsilon$?

Comment: That's correct. (Except for the use of "the sequence $e^{ixy_k}$", that should be "net", but that's probably just a slip due to exhaustion.)